# Не понимаю почему выводится крупное число перед решением

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int a,b;
    cin>>a;
    for (int i=0;i<a;i++) {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    for (int j = a; j != -1; j--) {
        cout<<arr[j]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вылезаете за диапазон индексов назначенных элементов массива.

```
for (int j = a - 1; j != -1; j--)
```